# JavaScript insertion into html

Tags: javascript, html

this is my first post. Let me preface this by saying that I know next to nothing about JS. I have a social media profile that allows users to design their profile page with simple HTML (akin to Myspace.)

My introduction to JS was receiving a code that allowed me to insert it despite it being blocked by the developers. I'm told both CSS and JS are blocked. This code allows me to add a background image to my entire profile page (not just the default sidebar.) I'd tried for weeks to do so with html with no avail.

I'd like to understand what it means/what it is doing. I'm starting to watch introductory JS videos, but I have a long road ahead to learn this language. Might anyone have a moment to explain in simple terms what this code is?

I attached the code. It's a jumbled mess. I'm so new I don't even know how to space it correctly.

```
<div id="inspt"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var _0x1d47=['MY SLUG URL HERE','ready','indexOf','location','.page-title'];(function(_0x423614,_0x1d4723){var _0x2f1570=function(_0x280602){while(--_0x280602){_0x423614['push'](_0x423614['shift']());}};_0x2f1570(++_0x1d4723);}(_0x1d47,0x17a));
var _0x2f15=function(_0x423614,_0x1d4723){_0x423614=_0x423614-0x0;
var _0x2f1570=_0x1d47[_0x423614];return _0x2f1570;};
$(document)[_0x2f15('0x3')](function(){var _0x40cd93='
<style>\x20ins.adsbygoogle\x20{\x20display:none;
\x20}\x20.bg-grey-50.padding-top-60.padding-top-sm-30\x20{\x20background-image:\x20url(MY BACKGROUND IMAGE LINK HERE)\x20}\x20</style>';
if(window[_0x2f15('0x0')]['href'][_0x2f15('0x4')](_0x2f15('0x2'))>-0x1){$(_0x2f15('0x1'))['append'](_0x40cd93);}}); 
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code has been purposefully obfuscated so that no one can understand it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Is there a way to make it intelligible so I can learn how it works?

Comment: You might have some luck with online un-obfuscators.

Comment: Thank you! Are there any you recommend?